# При использовании pm2 в режиме кластера работает только один процесс nodejs

Tags: node.js, pm2

Запускаю приложение nodejs менеджером pm2 в режиме кластера:

```
pm2 start /api/app.js --name api2 -i 4
```

Запускается 4 процесса :
[image: вывод pm2 list]

Но нагрузка только в одном процессе, и логи тоже только с него:
[image: вывод pm2 monit]

Answer (score 0):

Пишем тестовый сервер:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const rand = Math.random();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(`ololo ${rand}`);
    res.json({ok: rand});
});
app.listen(3002, 'localhost');
```

Запускаем его под pm2:

```bsh
./node_modules/.bin/pm2 start src/express-under-pm2.js --name api2 -i 4
```

Проверяем:

```
┌─────┬─────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  │ name    │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├─────┼─────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0   │ api2    │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ cluster │ 91541    │ 90s    │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 26.8mb   │ kolpak   │ disabled │
│ 1   │ api2    │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ cluster │ 91542    │ 90s    │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 26.8mb   │ kolpak   │ disabled │
│ 2   │ api2    │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ cluster │ 91543    │ 90s    │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 26.8mb   │ kolpak   │ disabled │
│ 3   │ api2    │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ cluster │ 91544    │ 90s    │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 27.9mb   │ kolpak   │ disabled │
└─────┴─────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

Делаем несколько запросов, чтобы убедиться, что ответы будут повторяться. Ответы должны повторяться так как в запущенном worker-е число в переменной `rand` не меняется:

```bsh
username@negroponta-mac:~/tmp/q $ curl http://localhost:3002
{"ok":0.8181942417429142}
{"ok":0.15886834916651726}
{"ok":0.17382555685734502}
{"ok":0.5360435879520078}
{"ok":0.8181942417429142}
{"ok":0.15886834916651726}
{"ok":0.17382555685734502}
{"ok":0.5360435879520078}
{"ok":0.8181942417429142}
```

*Наблюдаемый результат: ответы worker-ов повторяются.*

---

Запускаем бесконечный цикл, который будет постоянно обращаться к серверу:

```bsh
while true; do curl http://localhost:3002; done
```

Наблюдаем равномерную загрузку worker-ов:

```
username@negroponta-mac:~/tmp/q $ ./node_modules/.bin/pm2 monit

┌─ Process List ───────────────────────────────┐  
│[ 0] api2     Mem:  39 MB    CPU:  1 %  onlin │
│[ 1] api2     Mem:  41 MB    CPU:  1 %  onlin │
│[ 2] api2     Mem:  39 MB    CPU:  1 %  onlin │
│[ 3] api2     Mem:  40 MB    CPU:  2 %  onlin │


username@negroponta-mac:~/tmp/q $ ./node_modules/.bin/pm2 log api2

0|api2  | ololo 0.15886834916651726
2|api2  | ololo 0.17382555685734502
3|api2  | ololo 0.5360435879520078
1|api2  | ololo 0.8181942417429142
0|api2  | ololo 0.15886834916651726
2|api2  | ololo 0.17382555685734502
3|api2  | ololo 0.5360435879520078
```

---

Вывод: вы правильно запустили своё приложение под pm2. Приложение запущенное в таком режиме будет равномерно загружать worker-ов.